# In Ruby, is there a way to print out all the Global variables and Constants defined / predefined?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is there a way to print out all the Global variables and Constants defined / predefined?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `global_variables` method returns an array of all global variable names. To get the names of all the constants defined in a module, send `constants` to the relevant module. For example, to get all the constants that you can access without specifying a namespace, use `Object.constants`.

Comment: To expand on this - you may want to check ObjectSpace module as well.